# JQuery Mobile canvas field(signature) style issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile, cordova, canvas

In my cordova application i used Jquery mobile(v 1.3.2) and [thomas jbradly Sign plugin](http://thomasjbradley.ca/lab/signature-pad/#require-drawn).In my application i have one signature field(canvas to draw sign) and some fields.

Like below code:

```
<div data-role="page" id="page1">
        <div data-role="content">
            <div class="ui-grid-a">
                <div class="ui-block-a">
                        <button>Button1</button>
                </div>
            <div class="ui-block-b" style='margin-top: 2%;'>
                    <b><label>Label 1</label></b>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div data-role="fieldcontain"></div>
        <div id="signaturePart">
            <div class="sigPad">
                <b><label>Put Your Sign Here</label></b>
                <ul type="none">
                    <li class="clearButton"><a href="#clear">Clear</a></li>
                </ul>
                <div class="sig">
                    <canvas class="pad" width="550" height="200" id="mKundusskirt"></canvas>
                    <input type="hidden" name="output" class="output">
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

When put signature in canvas filed the duplicate of canvas field is displayed above the original field.
**Before Signing the canvas:**

[image]

**After Signing the canvas:**(Create duplicate of original canvas)

[image]

**NOTE***:

> When remove the Jquery mobile the signature field working fine.

For reference: [Signature Css](http://pastie.org/9609303)

[Signature Js](http://pastie.org/9609304)

Please help me to solve the problem..

Answer (score 0):

try to apply the CSS overflow:hidden on the div which contains the class="sig".